# NativeCrashListener: Exception dealing with report android.system.ErrnoException: read failed: EAGAIN

Tags: android, html, printing, io, android-file

I'm trying to generate an HTML file in order to print it later on, on a specific android tablet (Android 5.1.1), If the HTML file contains Arabic letters the HTML viewer and the app crashes.

after generating the HTML i make a print job to print it, then the android print adapter opens and try to render the Arabic HTML, the app crashes here with the error shown above.

Please help..

My code..

```
    WebSettings webSetting = webview.getSettings();

    webSetting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    webview.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
     htmlWebView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.MEDIUM);
    webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "finished" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error: " + error , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    });
    webView.loadUrl("file:///" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/reports/genFiles/" + filename);
```

Comment: Could you post your code and crashlogs?

Comment: hello, please check my updated question i posted the code, thank you.

Comment: and here is the crash log:

Comment: Exception dealing with report
                                                                   android.system.ErrnoException: read failed: EAGAIN (Try again)
at libcore.io.Posix.readBytes(Native Method)
at libcore.io.Posix.read(Posix.java:165)
at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.read(BlockGuardOs.java:230)
at android.system.Os.read(Os.java:350)

Comment: Please, post your method which creates a name of the file before save it.